# List index out of Range python2.7 looping based on first value

Tags: python, python-2.7, loops, if-statement

Good day may someone please help im trying to loop through a txt file based on the first value"tocken",it currently loops only if i specify the tockens e.g {600001130260} there are multiply tockens in the file all in the first row[0] id like it to iterate for each tocken/row and extract the specified info.

**The data file looks like this**

```
600001130260|005|||IN|2197|01||20160905210028
600001130260|100|005|00|VAT|VAT|VAT @ 14%|2,150.14
600001130260|100|013|00|TOT|CTOT|Total Due|86,578.93
600001130260|100|014|00|DD|DD|Due Date|2015/09/22|2015/10/15
600001130260|200|019|01||YDACON|Daily average consumption 79.325 kWh||
28002385859|000|||||LT|||T0IQ04960000000016400000000000000||
28002385859|100|005|00|CUR|CUR|Current Charges (Excl. VAT)|304.48
28002385859|100|006|00|VAT|VAT|VAT @ 14%|10.62
28002385859|100|013|00|TOT|CTOT|Total Due|26,451.75
28002385859|100|014|00|DD|DD|Due Date|2015/09/23
28002385859|150||23,149.02|1,686.37|1,233.57|382.79|0.00|26,451.75
```

**This is my code**

```
file1 = open(r"C:\Users\isaac.gumbi\Documents\jhb\Full test file.txt", 'r')
file2 = ""
with file1 as f:
    for line in f:
        tokens = line.split("|")

        keys = {'600001130260','118002191517','CTOT', 'CUR', 'Due Date', 
               'VAT', '020', '030', '010', '040', 'STOT', '000', '005',
                '050', '0100', 'BBF', 'INT','CIN', 'CTOT', 'DD', 'YVLEVY', 
                'YRREM'}

        if len(tokens) and tokens[0] in keys and tokens[5] == 'CTOT':
            Total_due = ' '.join(tokens[7:8])
            if Total_due == '' : Total_Due = "null"
            print ("Total_due", Total_due)
```

**This is my current  output**

```
('Total_due', '86,578.93\n')
('Total_due', '79,191.18\n')
```

i would like it to give me the output total_due without me specifying the tocken in [0]

Comment: "i would like it to give me the output total_due without me specifying the `tocken[0] in keys`" - so what is the purpose of checking `token[0] in keys`?  What alternative criteria should be used to determine `Total_Due` should be computed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want all values of `Total Due` ?
If so, you could simply do the following :

```py
sep = "|"
value_name = "Total Due"
result = []

with open("thefile.txt", 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        tokens = line.split(sep)
        try:
            ind_total_due = tokens.index(value_name) + 1
            result.append((value_name, tokens[ind_total_due]))
        except ValueError:
            continue
```

The result will be :

```py
[('Total Due', '86,578.93'),
 ('Total Due', '26,451.75'),
 ('Total Due', '3,483.28'),
 ('Total Due', '983.04'),
 ('Total Due', '- 197,358.33')]
```

The first "token" seems to be an unique identifier.
If you want a csv export and multiple column support you could go for something like this:

```py
token_sep = "|"
csv_sep = ";"

# Lambda function that whill format total due
float_formater = lambda string : float(
    string.replace(" ", "").replace(",", "")
)

# Attributes you want to parse
col_names = (
    ("Total Due", float_formater, 1),
    ("Due Date", None, 1),
)

# Python dictionary which associate to each identifier, a total due
# and a due date
records = {}

with open("thefile.txt", 'r') as f:
    for line in f:

        tokens = line.strip().split(token_sep)

        # We assume the first token is an identifier
        unique_id = tokens[0]

        # For each new identifier we create a new record and initialize 
        # total due and due date to an empty string
        if unique_id and unique_id not in records:
            records[unique_id] = {col_name: "" for col_name, _ in col_names}

        # then we look for values we are interesting in. If we find one, we can
        # update one value of the record
        for col_name, formatter, index_val in col_names:
            try:
                ind_col = tokens.index(col_name) + index_val 
                value = tokens[ind_col]

                if formatter:
                    value = formatter(value)

                records[unique_id][col_name] = value


            except ValueError:
                continue

# For an easier csv export we reformat the record dict to a list of values
list_values = [
    (unique_id,) + tuple((values[col] for col, _ in col_names))
    for unique_id, values in records.items()
]

# We can then easily write all the records one by one
with open("mycsv.csv", "w") as f:
    f.write(csv_sep.join(["id"] + [c for c, _ in col_names]))
    for values in list_values:
        print(values)
        f.write("\n")
        f.write(csv_sep.join(map(str, values)))
```

`mycsv.csv` :

```
id;Total Due;Due Date
112002209769;3483.28;2015/09/23
142002121343;-197358.33;
600001130260;86578.93;2015/09/22
28002385859;26451.75;2015/09/23
100002232416;983.04;2015/09/23
```

Comment: Thank you @H4kim i tried it out ,can you please help me in how i would go about writing the values to a csvfile or txt ,im currently struggling to

Comment: How are you getting that result i have to add a " print("Total Due", tokens[ind_total_due]) "

Comment: by printing the resulting list : `print(result)`
I edit my answer to make a csv export

Comment: Thankk you @H4kim this is great ,im currently writing the values and have also specified others to be printed out  with multiply try statements ,my output looks like: 
    87,558.93
    2015/09/22,its combining the total and duedate into one column i would like to have it split into seperate coulmns one for total and one for duedate

Comment: Ok, I'll modify my answer ;)

Comment: Can you please verify your output ,my output does not contain records it only imprints the headings,the output file is empty

Comment: Hello H4kim i hope you are well,is it possible for me to list values that are not necessarily "........index(col_name) + 1",but maybe .....(col_name)+2 or ....+4 ,Or if i can maybe use tocken 2 and 3 as the verifiers...eg tocken"100|013" = totaldue

Comment: Yes you could add it to column spectifications : `col_names = (("Total Due", float_formater, 1), ("Due Date", None, 1), ("otherColumn", None, 2))`. Then you'll be able to get the index of the value in the loop : `for col_name, formatter, ind in col_names: ... ind_col = tokens.index(col_name) + ind`

Comment: i get the error too many value to unpack for line 30  ......records[unique_id] = {col_name: "" for col_name, _ in col_names}

Comment: yes because now there is 3 values to unpack. You can solve this by replacing `records[unique_id] = {col_name: "" for col_name, _ in col_names}` by `records[unique_id] = {col_name[0]: "" for col_name in col_names}`

Comment: Hello @H4kim thank you ,can you please help me with one last query im trying to pull col_names = (
    ("Due Date", None, 2),
    ("Due Date", None, 1),
),instead i get either one